# NHibernate is ignoring ForeignKey property

Tags: c#, oracle, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

### Situation

The project I am working on at this moment uses NHibernate with Fluent NHibernate.
The Oracle database already exists and can't/shouldn't be changed.

The problem I am having is that Fluent NHibernate seems to ignore the `ForeignKey` property/method in the following code sample.

```
Table("PERSON_PACKET");
Id(x => x.Id, "ID").GeneratedBy.UuidHex("N");

// Some Map(...) methods

References(x => x.Packet)
    .Column("PKT_IDENTIFICATION")
    .ForeignKey("IDENTIFICATION")
    .Cascade.None()
    .Fetch.Select()
    .Not.LazyLoad();
```

**Can someone explain what is happening here?**

#### How I discoved this

This part of the database has the following structure:

[image: ERD]

All three these entities are actually Views and not Tables, but the tables behind it are similar.

The `PACKET` view has two similar fields. One called `IDENTIFICATION` which is a number, and one called `ID` that is the `IDENTIFICATION` with some other data concatenated and is a varchar.
`PACKET_PERSON` has the column `PKT_IDENTIFICATION` that has the same concatenated format as `PACKET.ID` (so not `PACKET.IDENTIFICATION`)

The weird thing is the above mapping worked, even though the wrong column was in the `ForeignKey` method. This mapping has worked since 2014.
I then tried changing the `ForeignKey` method to `ForeignKey("ID")` which worked too.

Finally I changed the method to `ForeignKey("JUST_SOMETHING_THAT_IS_NO_COLUMN")` and things kept working.

What is happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that method is there for schema generation. I think it equates to [this](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#toolsetguide-s1-2) part of the NH XML mapping.

From the documentation:

> ...specifies the name of the foreign key constraint generated for an association, use it on `<one-to-one>`, `<many-to-one>`, `<key>`, and `<many-to-many>` mapping elements.

This is why it's not having any observable effect. You would only see a foreign key constraint named `JUST_SOMETHING_THAT_IS_NO_COLUMN` if you generated a database from your mapping files.

If you're not going to generate a schema, your mapping could become:

```
References(x => x.Packet)
    .Column("PKT_IDENTIFICATION")
    .Cascade.None()
    .Fetch.Select()
    .Not.LazyLoad();
```

With no ill effect.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In that case I am wondering how NHibernate knows what column is referred to, as this database has no foreign key constrains, and the view has no primary key.

Comment: NHibernate does not inspect database schema and does not care about it. Only the model and the mapping matter. It infers from it what it needs to do its job.

Comment: It will use `Packet`'s mapping to work out its primary key and then use the `PKT_INDENTIFICATION` column you've specified to join the two.

Comment: @DavidOsborne I didn't think about that setting. The `ID` column is indeed set as primary key in the `Packet` mapping. Thanks for your answer.